# Sequelize - How to define ON DELETE action during model definition

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to ask you if it is possible to set ON DELETE action while defining a Sequelize model, for example:

```
sequelize.define('oAuthAccessTokens', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    accessToken: { type: Sequelize.STRING(256), allowNull: false },
    expires: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false },
    scope: Sequelize.STRING(255),
    clientId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(80),
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: 'oAuthClients',
            key: "clientId",
            **onDelete: "cascade"** // here is my try
        }
    },
    userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: 'oAuthUsers',
            key: "id",
            **onDelete: "cascade"** // here is my try
        }
    }
});
```

I know it's possible to pass a proper option to `hasOne()` method, but what about such a model definition? I hope there is a way which is not mentioned in the official documentation.

**Updated**

The problem is solved now. The `onDelete` attribute should be outside the `references` one.

```
sequelize.define('oAuthAccessTokens', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    accessToken: { type: Sequelize.STRING(256), allowNull: false },
    expires: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false },
    scope: Sequelize.STRING(255),
    clientId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(80),
        allowNull: false,
        onDelete: "cascade",
        references: {
            model: 'oAuthClients',
            key: "clientId",
        }
    },
    userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        onDelete: "cascade",
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: 'oAuthUsers',
            key: "id"
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved now. The `onDelete` attribute should be outside the `references` one.

```
sequelize.define('oAuthAccessTokens', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    accessToken: { type: Sequelize.STRING(256), allowNull: false },
    expires: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false },
    scope: Sequelize.STRING(255),
    clientId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(80),
        allowNull: false,
        onDelete: "cascade",
        references: {
            model: 'oAuthClients',
            key: "clientId",
        }
    },
    userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        onDelete: "cascade",
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: 'oAuthUsers',
            key: "id"
        }
    }
});
```